# BitcoinJ - Master Key from 12 word

Tags: wallet, bitcoinj, deterministic-wallets, seed

Is there any posibilities to:
1. Create deterministic seed from 12 or 24 word
2. Create Private Master key from this deterministic seed
3. Create deterministic wallet using private master key

in BitcoinJ